# Regular expression with awk return only column with one numeric character?

Tags: bash, awk

I have two different type of log lines and the field `$5` is:

```
ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf
3
```

How can write a regular expression with `awk` in order to extract only fields with one character?

This is my solution however it is not working and it will return everything!

`awk '/[0-9]\+/ {print $5}'`

I will be appreciated for any help?

Comment: you could use the condition `$5~/^.$/`, it explicitly matches a field with only one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's marginally longer to write but if you only care about the length of the field, I think it's clearer to use `length`:

```
awk 'length($5) == 1 { print $5 }' file
```

Otherwise, if you want to match a single character in the range `0` to `9`, that would be:

```
awk '$5 ~ /^[0-9]$/ { print $5 }' file
```

...or to match anything considered to be a digit in your locale:

```
awk '$5 ~ /^[[:digit:]]$/ { print $5 }' file
```

Some versions of awk (e.g. GNU awk) understand the shorthand `\d` instead of `[[:digit:]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
awk '$5~/^.$/ {print $5}' file.txt
```

To match only a digit:

```
awk '$5~/^[0-9]$/ {print $5}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
abcdX1yad45das ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf 3 foo
abcdX1yad45das ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf ffe5a6fb-2933-4c01-855d-3033933600bf 3 foo
abcdX2fad45das
abcdX3had45das
abcdX4wad45das
abcdX5mad45das

$ awk '$5~/^.$/ {print $5}' file.txt
3
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can u plz explain it why not using `\d` as I am looking for a number with the combination of {1}?

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the "+" sign.

```
awk '/[0-9]+/ {print $5}'
```